# Copying prototype of localstorage to an other object is giving `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Tags: javascript, object, local-storage

I wanted to make a ditto of localstorage into another object, below is how I did in chrome console,

```
var obj = {}
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, Object.getPrototypeOf(localStorage))
obj.setItem("a", 1) // this line throws below error
VM663:1 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

May I know how to fix this.

Comment: ```
var obj = Object.create(localStorage);
obj.setItem("a", 1)
```
same error for above usage also

Comment: No, you cannot do that (and not `obj = new Storage()` either). Why would you even want to? What did you intend to achieve by this? Where did you expect `a` to be stored?